# Polymer 1.0 paper-menu selected not working when scrolling to item in list

Tags: polymer

I have the following code which works when selecting an item at the top of the list; however when scrolling down and selecting an element at the bottom of the list it reselects the pervious selected item.

```
<div id="rolesDropDown" class="allRoles">
    <paper-menu id="rolesMenu" selected="{{selectedIndex}}"> 
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{roles}}">
            <div class="role">
                <div class="propName"><span>{{item.property.name}}</span></div> 
                <div class="roleTitle" id="lightText"><span>{{item.title}}</span></div> 
            </div>
        </template>
    </paper-menu>
</div>
```

---

```
selectedIndex:{
    type: Number,
    value: 0,
    notify: true,
    observer: "selectRole"
}

selectRole: function() { 
    console.log('inside select role method');
}
```